# Showing a image created with the GC lib

Tags: php, drawing

i have my test.php:

```
<?php

echo "Image:<br/>";

include('draw.php');

?>
```

and my draw.php:

```
<?php

$img = imagecreate(250,80);

...

header("Content-type: image/jpeg"); imagejpeg($img); imagedestroy($img);

?>
```

now, visiting test.php tells me that headers is already sent. How do i show the image in draw.php "realtime" (not by saving to server and loading it using img tag)?

?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to incorporate this into an html page, change `test.php` to this:

```
<?php
    echo "Image:<br/>";
    echo '<img src="draw.php" />'
?>
```

You could just as easily make it a static html page:

```
<html>
  <head>
   <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    Images: <br />
    <img src="draw.php" />
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Remove `echo "Image:<br/>";` from test.php and read carefully about HTTP headers http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php so that you don't make the same mistake again

Comment: Well that works because it will be the same as going directly to the draw.php. BUT i want to show the image with other content, like "Image: <br />"

Comment: Seems I misunderstood what you wanted to achieve.